# Asynchronous request in react-native

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, request

I use this piece of code to asynchronously make a request with React-Native, but it seems like it doesn't get it. The request has been tested separately and the data should be valid.

```
   var data = [{name: 'simon'}];
   const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', testedValidUrl, true);
   req.send();

   req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
   var name ="";
   function processRequest(e) {
      if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
      var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
      data[0].name = response.name;
      }
      // setTimeout(()=>{},1000);
    }
```

I thought that maybe it was because of concurrence and that the large array in the real application takes less time to construct than to get the data from the server. Adding setTimeout() did not fix it.

Comment: fetch api is much better option https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: You are setting the event listener after you have sent the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var data = [{name: 'simon'}];
   const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   function processRequest(e) {
      if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
      var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
      data[0].name = response.name;
   }
   req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
   req.open('GET', testedValidUrl, true);
   req.send();
   var name ="";
```

If you set the event handler, (onreadystatechange) after you send/open the request, the readyState has already changed and thus it won't be called.